# Interpretation of the random effect variance in lmer

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme

Sorry, I am new to linear mixed models. I run a linear mixed model and get the following Output:

[image]

I researched the yield and LAI of Sweetcorn. Yield and LAI of [A] pic was measured in ground-base using portable machine. In case of [B] pic , all data was recorded by UAV (Same field). So, the No. of data is different because of the measuring method.

Anyway, i run a linear mixed model using lmer in R and got the result sheet as above.

I am looking forward to report this result including random effect variance, however, it is too hard to understand the meaning of random effect variance exactly. My question is, what exactly does the random effects tells me (the variance is 53.92 and 52.59 in [A], 5.525 and 816.310 in [B])? How do i interpret the result of random effect?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you explain whether the Treatment and LAI are plot-level variables or measurement-level variables?

Comment: Good morning, Treatment is the experimental design (maybe the plot-level variables) and LAI is measured each plant(measurement level variable)

Answer (score 4):

Without knowing exactly what your variables measure (continous, centered, etc.), I can only speak to what I see. It appears that you have an intercepts-only model without random slopes. From what I can see, the random effects intercept here (53.92) is the variance *between* plots, whereas the residual random effects variance (52.59) is how much they vary *within* plots.This can also be interpreted as how much error there is in your model estimation of random effects.

As this model does not include random slopes, we cannot say for certain what the relationship is between each slope or if it is correlated with each intercept.

Comment: Thank u for your kind reply, sir. Based on the random effect result, Can we confirm which measuring method is better? Also, How to i say when i interpret the random-effect result in report? Additionally, i wonder that [A] pic result showed that the similar value of residual and plot variance, however, the valuse's gap become bigger in [B]. What is the reason?

Comment: One way of knowing which plots are higher or lower is using the `ranef` function, which will provide how much each intercept varies. Just plug in your model into the function, such as `ranef(model)`. It should spit out numbers that indicate if they are higher or lower than the grand mean, which is your random intercept listed in the summary. I also can't say with certainty which is "better" since I don't know enough about your data to say whats going on.

Comment: Some excellent papers on reporting LMER models are [Brown 2021](https://doi.org/10.1177/2515245920960351) and [Meteyard & Davies 2020](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jml.2020.104092)